# SQL date comparision in oracle developer

Tags: java, sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table with date column. But when I use the '>' operator the result set returned is not as expected.

`select * from table where birth_day > '10-jan-2020';`

expected result set should not have 10-jan-2020 value as in query '>' is used. But in result set I am seeing 10-jan-2020,11-jan-2020... Is this how sql behaves?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select * from table where birth_day >= to_date('2020.01.11', 'yyyy.mm.dd');
```

Comment: An Oracle date has a time part too, perhaps this is the cause of your problem,

Answer (score 0):

In oracle, `Date` datatype stores time too.

so you have multiple options to fetch result as follows:

```
select * from table where birth_day >= date '2020-01-10' + 1; 
-- all the birth_day having date >= 2020-01-10 00:00:00 will be included

select * from table where trunc(birth_day) > date '2020-01-10';  
-- trunc(birth_day) will trunc the date to starting of the day - 00:00:00 
-- so it will work without adding one day to your date '2020-01-10'
```